# What is the difference between firstChild and childNodes[1]?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between child node and child element in JavaScript DOM?

like e.g.

```
var myTbodyElement = myTableElement.firstChild;
```

and

```
var mySecondTrElement = myTbodyElement.childNodes[1];
```

Can we use first child and child node interchangeably?

Comment: the second one is the second child node - because programmers start counting at **0**

Comment: `.firstChild` would be exactly equivalent to `.childNodes[0]`, though, yes.

Comment: so child and nodes are same ? and is there difference between .children and .childnode

Comment: @cowboy `.children` returns the child _elements_. `.childNodes` returns the child nodes. All elements are nodes, but not all nodes are elements.

Comment: @cowboy `.children[0]` = `.firstElementChild`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.firstChild` is equivalent to `childNodes[0]`.

- `firstChild` returns the first child node
- `childNodes` returns a collection of all child nodes
- `firstElementChild` returns the first child element
- `children` returns a collection of all child *elements*

> can we substitute using first child and child node

Yes, if you only want to access the first one.

**Demo:**

```js
var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

var firstChild = d.firstChild;
var childNodes0 = d.childNodes[0];
var firstElementChild = d.firstElementChild;
var children0 = d.children[0];

console.log("d.childNodes.length is", d.childNodes.length);
console.log("firstChild",             firstChild.nodeName,        firstChild.textContent);
console.log("childNodes[0]",          childNodes0.nodeName,       childNodes0.textContent);
console.log("d.children.length is",   d.children.length);
console.log("firstElementChild",      firstElementChild.nodeName, firstElementChild.textContent);
console.log("children[0]",            children0.nodeName,         children0.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Some text<b>Some bold text</b>Some more text</div>
```